# Is there any specific narration from the Prophet pertaining to swimming?

Tags: sharia, hadith-interpretation, islamic-basis

There are various sites that insist on the virtue of swimming by attributing it to the Sunnah. I like to know the truth about this matter in regards to what the Prophet actually said.

I know that:

https://sunnah.com/ahmad/2/229

I am not certain of other sites in regards to what the Prophet said in regards to swimming.

Request clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I found no direct references to the prophet pertaining to swimming. I want to know if the prophet made any comments pertaining to swimming. If there are none - I would like to know that as well.

Comment: Please read through the answer on the linked duplicate. The last section references the (weak) ahadith attributed to the prophet.